# C++ using exceptions

Tags: c++

I have a simple question

If I have a code with try and catch, like this

```
try
{
...
}
catch(exception& ex)
{
   AfxMessageBox(ex.what());
}
```

Will this catch all the exceptions, even exceptions like bad pointer, etc? And also, if this code is there and for example, the code has a pointer, or memory problem, will it still crash? Or do I have to use

```
catch(...)
```

But how can I exactly pinpoint what was the reason of an enentual crash then?

Comment: That should catch all C++ exceptions being thrown that are based on the `std::exception` class. But if an exception is being thrown that is *not* based on `std::exception` then that will not be caught. Also, some things are *called* exceptions but they are not C++ exceptions being thrown, but low-level CPU exceptions ("crashes") which can not be caught this way (if at all).

Comment: There are no guarantees with bad pointers, other than the guarantee that **anything** can happen. There is explicitly no guarantee, that accessing a bad pointer will have any predictable outcome. If your program crashes, and you have no idea why, you need to go an hire a developer to find out.

Comment: The best way to handle unhandled exception is to let the exception crash the program and use a debugger. For undefined behaviour it's trickier since it can cause a seemingly normal behaviour and not cause any error (check out clang's UB sanitiser if you can use clang). Having a "top level" ``try/catch`` that catch everything is almost always a bad design

Answer (score -1, accepted):

std::exception will handle only these kind of exception .http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception.
if you are not sure what all kind of exception your try block can throw and you dont want to terminate your process you can blindly go for catch(...).
If you know what all kind of exception your try block can throw and that all comes under std::exception go with it.

Comment: `catch(...)` will only catch C++ exceptions. The OP is talking about SEH exceptions (like access violations), that aren't caught by a `catch(...)` clause. This answer is totally not useful.

Answer (score 3):

If your code has undefined behavior, that *could* cause almost anything to happen, including throwing an exception.

Visual C++ 6 did (by default) convert some OS-level exceptions like that to C++ exceptions, as you're discussing here. It apparently didn't work out very well though--their newer compilers do *not* do this by default. If you really want that behavior, they do provide a compiler switch (e.g., /EHa) that will let you do that--but most people probably wouldn't advise using that.

Windows Structured Exception Handling has a `SetUnhandledExceptionHandler`, which will let you catch SEH exceptions, sort out what exception you've caught, and throw a C++ exception you feel is appropriate to signify what's happened. This, however, is a fairly manual process (i.e., it's up to you to write something like a switch statement to sort out the structured exception you've caught, and decide what C++ exception to throw in response to that).

Likewise, on Linux you could set up handlers for various signals, and throw exceptions in response to them. You may need to get a bit tricky about this though. The problem is that POSIX signals are delivered asynchronously, and you're *very* limited in what you can do in them. Nearly the only thing the signal handler itself can do is set a flag of type `sig_atomic_t`, and outside code can (when convenient) check its value, and if it's set, throw an exception. Mixing signals and exceptions is generally a rather non-trivial undertaking though.

As far as `catch(...)` goes, it'll only catch C++ exceptions, so it'll only catch things like memory problems as noted above, if you use it along with some sort of translation to create a C++ exception from the structured exception/signal. As to what you can do there: it's really pretty limited. You can't get any information about the exception that happened at all. At least when I've used it, it was pretty much a last-ditch thing that attempted to manage as orderly of a shut-down as possible, simply because by the time it was entered, any possibility of doing anything more intelligent had been exhausted in more specific handlers.

Comment: Instead of opting out of standardized exception handling using compiler switches, it is a common solution to set up an unhandled exception filter instead, dumping diagnostics from where the (SEH) exception originated. That works for uncaught C++ exceptions just as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is a confusion about different kinds of errors so here is an explanation about different errors and what to do about them. There are three kinds of errors that can happen

1. Compile error
2. Runtime error due to triggering undefined behaviour
3. Runtime error due to system limitations

Here is a list what you need to do about these three

**Compile error** Your compiler is your friend. Fix your code, but try to avoid circumventing the type system.

**Triggering undefined behaviour** It looks like you have this kind of problem somewhere in your code. In this case, you have a runtime bug. What you may have done

1. Dereferenced an invalid pointer
2. Performed integer division with zero
3. Used an unsupported assembly-level instruction
4. Passed an already freed pointer to free

To find problems like solve 1-3, you use the debugger. Also the `assert` macro is useful. Notice that problems of type 1 can be introduced by failing to check whether or not some functions allocating system resources failed. If so, see *Runtime error due to system limitations*.

Problems of type 4 are harder to find, since you will notice the problem upon the next `malloc`. On GNU/Linux, running your program through `valgrind` is your safest bet. I do not know anything about Windows tools for this.

**Runtime error due to system limitations** This is where you use exceptions. You could not foresee that a user specified file did not exist, or was encoded in a non-decodable way. Or you try to bring up OpenGL, but the user has not up-to-date graphics drivers, or you are on a remote X11 connection. To "solve" these problems you check the system level return values, and bail out through an exception, that will be caught by your nearest catch statement.